# Why application.properties is not executing properties after applying spring security in spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, application.properties

I have created an spring-boot application. It was working fine all the *css* and *js* were mapping perfectly with my *jsp* pages and application was able to map to my *jsp* pages as well. By appication.properties file in resources folder.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
server.port=8181
```

But since I have enabled Spring security I am not able to do that I needed to initialise @bean class

```
@Bean
  public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
      InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
      viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return viewResolver;
  }
```

It is weird. Can anybody help me with it?

Thank you in advance,

Priyal shah.

Comment: Any error or exception?

Comment: @Alien if i don't apply Bean it gives me 500 error Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'login' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'] with root cause

Comment: How have you enabled security... You shouldn't need to do anything for it.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your class is extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class like below sample.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.package")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfigs extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done that already .@Alien i need an answer why application.properties is not working?

Comment: and also i am not able to access my css and js file which are in src/main/resources/static/*    i used spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/** in application.properties how do i make it work without it ?@Alien

Comment: you are not able to access css because @EnableWebMvc annotation will disable Spring Boot's auto-configuration of Spring MVC.

Comment: okay, so how do i access that css? I tried removing **@EnableWebMvc** it didn't work. @Alien